# AWS Cognito - S3 Access using IAM role

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Currently I am working on a use case, where I need to authenticate web application users with AWS Cognito and provide access to the user specific folders in S3 bucket. For this I am using JavaScript at browser side and able to authenticate users.

I have created an IAM policy where I am trying to restrict the S3 access to user specific folders to authenticated users. Somehow, this policy is not working.

The policy that I am trying out here is given below:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cognito-identity:*",
            "mobileanalytics:PutEvents",
            "cognito-sync:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mycognitobuckettest",
        "Condition": {
            "StringLike": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    "cognito/mycognitobuckettest/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/",
                    "cognito/mycognitobuckettest/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
                ],
                "s3:delimiter": [
                    "/"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mycognitobuckettest/cognito/mycognitobuckettest/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
    }
]}`
```

If I remove the `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` from the resource path I am able to access the S3 bucket. However, if I put this into the resource path and also in condition key, I am getting access denied error.

As per my understanding the value for `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` is the region ID and uuid, which you can get like this `var identityID = AWS.config.credentials.identityId`

I am trying to list the objects in the resource path and below is the JavaScript code that I am using to list objects

```
var listObjectParms = {Bucket: bucketName, Delimiter: '/', Prefix: bucketPrefix};

    s3.listObjects(listObjectParms, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
            console.log("LIST OBJECT successful", data);
        }
    });
```

What is the exact value for `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}`?

I have created the folder in the S3 bucket according to the identity ID that I am receiving.

I got stuck at this point right now.
All you are welcome to provide any help regarding to solve this issue.

Thanks,

Avinash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue recently. This ${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub} value isn't anything from your cognito user pool. It is the Identity id you get from cognto identity.

> eg: us-east-1:aaaaaaa-bbbb-1111-ccccccccc11f

You can get this id in javascript sdk for cognito by using the [get_id](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html#getId-property) method

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per your suggestion, I tried to use the AWS.CognitoIdentity.getId() method to get the cognito identity. However, I found that  in both cases, I am getting the same Cognito Identity id. i.e.var identityID = AWS.config.credentials.identityId; and AWS.CognitoIdentity.getId() are returning the same values. For example :us-east-1:1aae78bd-3688-4ba2-a38f-717d61cafb5d

Comment: What have you set as the bucketPrefix? It should be the identity id as that is the only path you are allowed access to

Comment: Thanks again Ninad. The bucketPrefix I am using here is something like this BUCKET PREFIX ::  cognito/mycognitobuckettest/us-east-1:1aae78bd-3688-4ba2-a38f-717d61cafb5d

Comment: Can you giving it put access and check if you are able to upload a file using cognito credentials?

Comment: You can also try the list bucket command again but include a forward slash in the end like `cognito/mycognitobuckettest/us-east-1:1aae78bd-3688-4ba2-a38f-717d61cafb5d/`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188586/discussion-between-avinash-and-ninad-gaikwad).

Comment: Please select as correct answer if it solved your issue.